# Get pandas groupby object to ignore missing dataframes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

i'm using pandas to read an excel file and convert the spreadsheet to a dataframe. Then i apply groupby and store the individual groups in variables using get_group for later computation.
My issue is that the input file isn't always the same size, sometimes the groupby will result in 10 dfs, sometimes 25 etc. How to i get my program to ignore if a df is missing from the intial data?

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, 0, skiprows=3, parse_cols='A,B,C,E,F,G',
                   names=['Result', 'Trial', 'Well', 'Distance', 'Speed', 'Time'])
df = df.replace({'-': 0}, regex=True) #replaces '-' values with 0
df = df['Trial'].unique()
gb = df.groupby('Trial') #groups by column Trial

trial_1 = gb.get_group('Trial     1')
trial_2 = gb.get_group('Trial     2')
trial_3 = gb.get_group('Trial     3')
trial_4 = gb.get_group('Trial     4')
trial_5 = gb.get_group('Trial     5')
```

Say my initial data only has 3 trials, how would i get it to ignore trials 4, 5 later? My code runs when all trials are present but fails when some are missing :( It sounds very much like an if statement would be needed, but my tired brain has no idea where...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `gb.groups` will return a dict of the group names and labels: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html so you can just use these to get the groups

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but how does that help me?

Comment: Because you get a dict of the groups you don't need to hard code the number of groups in your code

Comment: Did you see my answer? You get a dict of the group names and levels, you then use the group names and pass these to `get_group`, so for instance, `gb_dict.keys()` returns you a list of the group names you can then pass these to `get_group`

Comment: Yep I'm an idiot, just re-read your answer. It's all working now! You're a star thank you so much and apologies for the dumb Qs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping you can get the groups using attribute `.groups` this returns a dict of the group names, you can then just iterate over the dict keys dynamically so you don't need to hard code the size:

```
In [22]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'grp':list('aabbbc'), 'val':np.arange(6)})
df

Out[22]:
  grp  val
0   a    0
1   a    1
2   b    2
3   b    3
4   b    4
5   c    5

In [23]:
gp = df.groupby('grp')
gp.groups

Out[23]:
{'a': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'b': Int64Index([2, 3, 4], dtype='int64'),
 'c': Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')}

In [25]:    
for g in gp.groups.keys():
    print(gp.get_group(g))

  grp  val
0   a    0
1   a    1
  grp  val
2   b    2
3   b    3
4   b    4
  grp  val
5   c    5
```

Comment: okay, i get what you mean now. thanks for explaining! i end up with this though
    gb_dict = gb.groups

    gb_dict['Trial     1']
Out[162]: 
    [0L,
     1L,
     2L,
     3L,

and so forth, it seems to have lost the original values and formatting - i would like the output to be in a dataframe still to preserve the structure!

Comment: Please edit your question with any additional code and info, don't put this in comments